# VectorFeature in a shapefile for a road network

Tags: performance, vector, netlogo, shapefile, feature-selection

I am using this code to create my roadnetwork in Netlogo from a shapefile. However, I got an error in foreach **gis:vertex-lists-of ?** because **?** is not recognised as VectorFeature in my VectorDataSet *roads*.

How can I solve this issue?

```
to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads [ ; each polyline
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of ? [ ; each polyline segment / coordinate pair
      foreach ? [ ; each coordinate
        let location gis:location-of ?
        if not empty? location [ ; some coordinates are empty []
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color green
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set hidden? true
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]


end
```

Comment: it looks like you wrote the code in NetLogo 5, but are now trying to run it in NetLogo 6. There was a major change in the way `foreach` works, as well as other primitives that used '?' Have a look at `foreach` in the dictionary for examples of the new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NetLogo are you using?

It looks like you’re using the old `?` task syntax in your `foreach`s. In 6.0, we replaced the `?` syntax with the `->` syntax. So your code would change as follows:

```
to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads [ polyline ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of polyline [ segment ->
      foreach segment [ coordinate ->
        let location gis:location-of coordinate
        if not empty? location [ ; some coordinates are empty []
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color green
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set hidden? true
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]
end
```

You can read about the transition to the -> syntax here: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#changes-for-netlogo-60

You can read about the -> and anonymous procedures in general here: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures